# Does the Conversational Actions sunset impact Actions that use Dialogflow agents?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

With Google having recently announced the sunsetting of Conversational Actions, I have yet to find any confirmation that this impacts all conversational experiences such as those created in the Actions Console that import across from Dialogflow. The [sunsetting info page](https://developers.google.com/assistant/ca-sunset) suggests that you can check to see if your action is impacted by checking the Actions Console for a Conversational Action banner. I have created some Actions using Dialogflow agents that run on devices like Raspberry Pi etc through the use of the [Google Assistant Service SDK](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/python). These older projects aren't showing this banner, however it does display if I try and create a Custom Action directly through the Actions Console. Not quite sure yet whether or not I should have any quiet confidence that I won't be impacted come the sunset date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this will impact Actions that use Dialogflow.

***ALL*** Conversational Actions will be shut down after June 13, 2023.

The catch, however, is that the Dialogflow agent, itself, will continue to exist since Dialogflow Essentials is not being shut down as part of this.

It does look like some Dialogflow-based actions are only showing the banner on some screens in the console. You should be able to confirm in the actions Console by clicking on the "Overview" tab on top.

[image: Actions Console showing Overview tab and shutdown banner]

Comment: Thanks! Just thought I would chime back in and say that I migrated from Conversational Actions to using the Python client for Dialogflow. Simple stuff!